# Handlebars each with count

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I can't figure out a case with handlebars.
My data looks like this:

```
items : [
  {
    name : "foo"
  },
  {
    name : "bar"
  },
  {
    name : "bacon"
  },
  {
    name : "burger"
  }
]
```

In my template I want to create lists of size 3, so the final html should look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li>bacon</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>burger</li>
</ul>
```

For now I have this in my Handlebars template:

```
<ul>
{{#each items}}
 <li>{{name}}<li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

So I end up with this:

```
<ul>
<li>foo</li>
<li>bar</li>
<li>bacon</li>
<li>burger</li>
</ul>
```

Do I need to create a Helper? How can I create it? Something like extending the default #each helper and adding an extra dom element each X iteration (eg 0, 3, 6, 9 ...)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answers, I prefer to handle the logic into a Handlebar Helper. I managed to do it, here is the code :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('list', function(context, options) {

var ret = "",
  listLength = 3,
  u = 0;

for(var i=0, j=context.length; i<j; i++) {

if( i % listLength === 0  ) {
    u = 0;
    ret += '<ul>';
}

ret +=  options.fn(context[i]);

if( u === listLength - 1 ) { // Zero indexed
    ret +='</ul>';
}

u++;
}

return ret;
});
```

And the template :

```
{{#list items}}
     <li>{{name}}</li>
  {{/list}}
```

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to create a custom helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("separateList", function( arr, options ) {
  // Here we only apply one line, but implement your separation logic in here
  return options.fn( arr[0] ); // pass a single arr item here
});
```

Then in your templates:

```
{{#separateList arr}}
  <li>{{content}}</li>
{{/separateList}}
```

That's basic implementation, but you can whatever you need to:

- http://handlebarsjs.com/#helpers
- http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#iterators

Answer (score 0):

Divide the items array into sub-arrays containing three objects each, let's call it itemsThree. Likes this:

```
itemsThree = [
    [
        {
            name : "foo"
        },
        {
            name : "bar"
        },
        {
            name : "bacon"
        } 
    ], 
    [
        {
            name: "burger"
        }
    ]
];
```

(Don't create this manually obviously.)

Then loop through each sub-array in it's own `<ul>`, and loop through each sub-array and put the objects in `<li>`.

Makes sense?